# Automapper: How to flatten complex object to plain object

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-8

```
 public class Complex
{
    public A A { get; set; }
    public A B { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    public int a1 { get; set; }
    public int a2 { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int b1 { get; set; }
    public int b2 { get; set; }
}
//----------------Source Object End Here---------------------

public class Simple  <----[This Simple class has only properties of A class]
{
    public int aa1 { get; set; }
    public int aa2 { get; set; }
}
//----------------Destination Object End Here---------------------

CreateMap<A, Simple>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.aa1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.a1))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.aa2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.a2))

// Mapper IS NOT AVAILABLE HERE AS I AM USING PROFILE BASED CONFIGURATION
CreateMap<Complex, Simple>()
    .ConvertUsing(src => Mapper.Map<A, Simple>(src.A)); <------Error at this line

//----------------Automammer config End Here---------------------
```

How to flatten from `Complex` to `Simple`? I don't wish to map `Complex.A` to `Simple` one by one again in the `Complex` to `Simple` config as it is already configured above.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html

Comment: I don't wish to stick to the convention of the Source object name and property name. Any more suggestion?

Comment: Then you can write a custom naming convention or do it by hand, as you've tried above. I would create a map from Complex to Simple with MapFrom. You don't need ConvertUsing here.

Comment: I figured out with another overloaded method of `ConvertUsing`. Posted as an answer to have greater visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out with another overloaded method of `ConvertUsing`

```
CreateMap<Complex, Simple>()
.ConvertUsing((src,ctx) => {
     return ctx.Mapper.Map<Complex, Simple>(src.A)
});
```

I feel this overloaded method has quite a multiple possibilities and flexibility. I don't have further issue of accessing `Mapper` directly as mentioned in the question. This overloaded method has its own context parameter (`ResolutionContext`). We can use `Mapper` from this context parameter like `ctx.Mapper.Map<Complex, Simple>(src.A)`